# Chromedriver got black screen through Jenkins agent

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, screen-capture

We have automation scripts developed in java with Cucumber + Selenium + Chromedriver and runs on multiple jenkins agents (windows). After some our agent machine got the Chrome v59 upgrades, the screen capture feature are broken in our test scripts. The captured screen is an black image. The agents in Chrome v58 are still working fine. Meanwhile, the test scripts are running fine on the jenkins agents if we login with remote desktop and command line to launch.

Here are some more details:

- Jenkins agents are on Windows 10 VM.
- Selenium-Java: 3.4
- Chromedriver: 2.30
- Chrome: Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

We have some test features are relying on the screen capture to verify some images, so that we are only able to verify our application in PhantomJS for now.  Any helps would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.
Cong

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same issue with Bamboo agents.
Using 
Browser.Driver.TakeScreenshot().SaveAsFile(path, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png)
instead of GetScreenshot() solved the problem for now.